# What's the word for billing based on partial usage?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When I moved into my new apartment, the first bill only charged me for what I used from the 3rd (when I moved in) to the 12th of the month. This is called [insert word here] billing.

Another word or phrase that describes this same situation but doesn't fit into the previous sentence is also acceptable.

Comment: "Prorated", perhaps?

Comment: That's it! I knew the word, I just couldn't think of it

Comment: @HotLicks Post as answer?

Comment: Not suitable here, for the apartment example, but in same cases PAYG (pay as you go) would work.

Comment: Pro rata rather than 'prorated', surely?

Comment: @Spagirl In North American English, *pro rata* has apparently been vernacularized to *prorated*. Here in the U.S., I've seen and heard "prorated" used in this context quite a bit

Comment: @NickWeinberg Oh, well. We live and learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hot Licks via comments:

[prorated](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prorate?q=prorated)

> *VERB [WITH OBJECT] chiefly North American*
>
> Allocate, distribute, or assess pro rata:
> bonuses are prorated over the life of a player’s contract